# Two men consequently flip a «fair» coin (possible outcomes are Head and Tail).

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

Two men consequently flip a «fair» coin (possible outcomes are Head and Tail). 
A winner is defined to be a player who produces a Head first. 
What is the probability that the first player (he begins a game) will be a winner? Let X be a random variable which shows a number of flips in the series $TTT…H$
 which describes one session of this game. What is the expectation E(X)?
my solution for first :
$$p=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}(1-p).$$  $p=2/3$. 
what about second part ?

Comment: Between this and [your prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3478298/we-have-the-box-containing-m-red-and-nblue-balls) it looks like you are just posting your homework for us to do for you.  This question is a routine application of the [Geometric Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)

Comment: not homework and improve my skills and try for some problems

Comment: thoese problems in exam  from universities lasts years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second part the reasoning is similar to that of the first part.

Let $E$ be the expected number of throws.

$$E=\frac12+\frac12(E+1),$$

since after the first throw either you stop (head, probability $1/2$) or you continue (tail, probability $1/2$) and in this second case your new expected number is $E+1$.

Thus $E=2$.