# what is the expected number of rounds I play this game, or on average, how many matches do I play until I lose the game?

Tags: probability, expected-value

I play a game (you can think of it as a coin tossing game) where the probability of winning a round is equal to $p$ for each round (so you can think of if you get a head $H$, you win, probability of getting a head is $p$). The game ends when I lose two rounds in a row ( so you lose if you get two subsequent tails $T$, probability of getting a seat is $(1-p)$). The question is, what is the expected number of rounds I play this game, or on average, how many matches do I play until I lose the game?
Thank you for your help in finding the answer! Can we solve this using Markov chain idea?

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2845196/expected-number-of-coin-flips-for-2-consecutive-heads-for-first-time)

Comment: Thanks, Can we solve this using idea from the Markov chain?

Comment: Sure. States, other than Start and End, are determined by the prior roll. Easy to write out the transitions.

Comment: can you write in details please?

Comment: One of the posted solutions to the linked duplicate uses a Markov approach to solve it for a fair coin. Just modify that.